# ValueError: Shape must be rank 3 but is rank 2. A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to use Tensorflow [Functional API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional) to define a multi input neural network.

This is my code:

```
from keras_self_attention import SeqSelfAttention
from tensorflow import keras
Input1 = Input(shape=(120, ),name="Input1")
Input2 = Input(shape=(10, ),name="Input2")
embedding_layer = Embedding(30,5,  input_length=120,)(Input1) 
lstm_layer = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=512))(embedding_layer)                  
attention=SeqSelfAttention(attention_activation='sigmoid')(lstm_layer) 
merge = concatenate([attention, Input2])
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, None, 1024), (None, 10)].
```

If I change shape of Input2 to (None,10, ), then I get this error:

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 3 but is rank 2 for '{{node model/concatenate/concat}} = ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32](model/dense/BiasAdd, model/Cast_1, model/concatenate/concat/axis)' with input shapes: [?,?,1024], [?,10], [].
```

and if I change shape of Input2 to (1,10, ), then I get this error:

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 3 but is rank 2 for '{{node model/concatenate/concat}} = ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32](model/dense/BiasAdd, model/Cast_1, model/concatenate/concat/axis)' with input shapes: [?,?,1024], [?,10], [].
```

How can I reshape output of attention layer from (None, None, 1024) to something which I can concatenate with (None, 10)?

Comment: So I take it you want to concatenate `Input2` with every element in the sequence?

Comment: Yes. I only have one sequence in input and I want to apply self attention to it and then concatenate with another input. How can I do that? I am getting the error which I explained above.

Comment: Check out `tf.tile`. You need to tile `Input2` `N` times, where `N` is the number of timesteps in output of  `attention`.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal Even attention layer is not working and I get IndexError: list index out of range (This error message is related to line which is about attention). Any idea how to set the hyper parameters and/or place layers one after another?

Answer (score 0):

The inputs for concatenate layer will not have matching dimensions. You can add a reshape layer in front of the concatenate layer to alleviate this issue.

```
[(None, None, 1024), (None, 10)].
```

Here one is three and one is two. Reshape the first input to `[None,1024]` or reshape the second input to `[None, 1 , 10]` whichever suits your need.

```
reshape_layer = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1024,))(attention)
merge = concatenate([reshapelayer, Input2])
```